# How do I add a button to the end of items in a ListView in ReactNative?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, react-native

This is what I tried but "Show unlinked tags" appears at the bottom, not after the last item.

```
render() {

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.title}> Settings Children </Text>
      <ListView
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={(rowData)=> <Text>{rowData}</Text>}
      />
      <View style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Show unlinked tags</Text>
      </View>

  </View>

)
}
```

[View image!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRJ27.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR:** React native doesn't provide a button component, use this https://github.com/ide/react-native-button

**Full:**

`npm install react-native-button --save`

then use it as

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import Button from 'react-native-button';

  export default class ExampleComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);
    // ...
    }
    _handlePress() {
      console.log('Pressed!');
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <View>
          <View>
            <ListView
                      dataSource={ this.state.dataSource }
                      renderRow={ (rowData) => <Text>
                                                 { rowData }
                                               </Text> } />
          </View>
          <View>
            <Button
                    style={ { fontSize: 20, color: 'green' } }
                    styleDisabled={ { color: 'red' } }
                    onPress={ () => this._handlePress() }>
              Press Me!
            </Button>
          </View>
        </View>
        );
    }
  }
```

Comment: I know that, but the button "Press me!" is still at the bottom of the page, I want that the Button,Title or any other component to be right under the ultimate item. As you can see in my image <ListView> fills all the Screen.

Answer (score 3):

you can use renderFooter to render view after your list.

```
renderFooter = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.button}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Show unlinked tags</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
render() {

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.title}> Settings Children </Text>
    <ListView
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={(rowData)=> <Text>{rowData}</Text>}
      renderFooter={this.renderFooter}
    />
  </View>
)
}
```